# Is it correct to write that if $dP = \frac{-h\cdot d\lambda}{\lambda^2}$ then $\Delta P = \frac{-h\cdot \Delta \lambda}{\lambda^2}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, physics

I was studying high school-level physics and came across a problem,

Which of the following relationships of Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle are correct?

1. $\Delta P \cdot \Delta x \geq \frac{h}{4\pi}$
2. $\Delta E \cdot \Delta t \geq \frac{h}{4\pi}$
3. $\Delta \lambda\cdot\Delta x\leq \frac{-\lambda^2}{4\pi}$
4. $\Delta V \cdot \Delta x \geq \frac{h}{4\pi m}$

I was able to figure out that all are correct but for the third one, I derived it this way:

The momentum of a photon is $P=\frac{h}{\lambda}$, so if we differentiate it w.r.t. wavelength $\lambda$, we get $$\frac{dP}{d\lambda} = \frac{-h}{\lambda^2}$$$$\implies dP = \frac{-h\cdot d\lambda}{\lambda^2}$$ After that what I did is that I wrote, $$\Delta P = \frac{-h\cdot\Delta\lambda}{\lambda^2}$$ And substituted this in expression 1. Though, I don't think this is the correct way to do it. Can anyone tell me if it is correct? If not, how should we solve this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having $P = h/\lambda$ , we can get :
$P+\Delta P = h/(\lambda+\Delta\lambda)$

Hence :
$P+\Delta P - P = h/(\lambda+\Delta\lambda) - h/\lambda$

$\Delta P = h[1/(\lambda+\Delta\lambda) - 1/\lambda]$

$\Delta P = h[(\lambda - (\lambda+\Delta\lambda))/(\lambda+\Delta\lambda)\lambda]$

$\Delta P = h[ -\Delta\lambda/(\lambda^2+\lambda\Delta\lambda)]$

$(\lambda^2+\lambda\Delta\lambda) \approx (\lambda^2)$

Hence :
$\Delta P = h[ -\Delta\lambda/\lambda^2]$

$\Delta P = -h\Delta\lambda/\lambda^2$

Comment: So, what we have basically done here is $\Delta f = f(x + h) - f(x)$, right? In our case, momentum is a function of wavelength as $P(\lambda) = \frac{h}{\lambda}$ so $$\Delta P = P(\lambda + \Delta\lambda) - P(\lambda)$$ Is this a correct way to write it?

Comment: Correct : We use finite Difference "Delta" here.